# How i can build and run my app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can i resolve this? After building my app on android studio and running on my phone it works fine but when i share it to another phone it says "There was error parsing this package"

Comment: Did you share the debug APK?

Comment: Sorry which is the debug apk?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably one of the following:

1. You set a minimum SDK version that is not supported in your friend's device. or maybe you added other restrictions in your app that prevents the APK from being installed on that device.
2. The APK you're trying to install is considered to be coming from an "unknown source", The Android system prevents you from installing apps from sources that are not known to the system.

To install that APK on your friend's device, you need to enable installing APKs from unknown sources, this setting is by default disabled and can be enabled from the device settings, on some devices you can find this option under Security settings, and on other devices it can be found under the Apps settings